# Remove new line from txt file in mac

Tags: shell, newline

I want to remove new line from txt files. I used tr -d '\n' < file.txt but I didn't see any difference. Is there any other option?

Comment: if the file was created on windows, use `dos2unix myFile` first. Also depending on OS and "source" of your `tr` code, you may have to use `\013` instead of `\n`. (just noticed your title, Mac), definitely `\013`). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your `tr` command will delete newlines from every where including non-empty lines.

Using inline sed you can delete all empty lines (including ones with just spaces):

```
sed -i.bak '/^ *$/d' file
```